# Finding second highest salary in all the companies

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to find second highest salary in all companies in my table

```
Name   Company Salary

alex    abc    50000
bert    abc    23000
charly  abc    45555
doris   xyz    34444
ellen   xyz    67777
fred    xyz    67771
```

i mentioned only 2 companies such as tcs and hcl but in my scenario there might be more than 200 companies so i cant use WHERE clause or UNION so please help me

Comment: So how about `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I really hope these are example data and not real ones. If they are real data, I think I found out who at least two persons in your sample are. I don't think those persons would like that his salary is now known.

Comment: select max(salary) from company group by company this can be used for finding maximum value but for second highest salary

Comment: Okay, I identified all but 2 of the people in your data. Really, not cool.

Comment: @DarkDust see thats just a name why you are making politics about it i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an analytical function like `dense_rank` to generate a numbering. In this case `dense_rank` or `row_number` are more suitable than `rank`, because the latter can have gaps in the numbering in which case you won't get any result at all. This happens when there are two persons with the same highest salary. If you use `rank`, those persons will both be ranked `1`, and the next person will have rank `3`.

I didn't understand whether you want the second highest overall, or per company, but I've show both. You can just filter by the other rank if you need the other one.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT
    Name, 
    Company,
    Salary,
    dense_rank() over (order by Salary DESC) as OverallSalaryRank,
    dense_rank() over (partition by Company order by Salary DESC) as SalaryRankPerCompany
  FROM
    SALARIES s)
WHERE
  SalaryRankPerCompany = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement will order your data for salary from max to min, and it will add the rank position for every company.

The `WHERE` condition will filter them on the second position. As suggested, I use `DENSE_RANK` to obtain a "second place" also if two employers have equal salaries.

```
SELECT Company, Salary 
  FROM ( SELECT Company, Salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) sal_rank
           FROM mytable ) 
WHERE sal_rank = 2;
```

Comment: With `rank` you risk not getting any results at all.